# Improve Spring batch FlatFileItemWriter performance

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on a spring batch project to write around 10 million records, my batch size is 60K items, while monitoring performance i see lots of delay in the writing step.
Can i set buffer size for the writer or is there anything that i can do to overcome this issue and enhance performance?
Regards

Comment: Do you have some numbers about the delays? The writer will buffer all lines before flushing them to the output file. So in your case, you will have a String with 60K buffered lines on each chunk. Have you tried reducing the chunk size? What would you consider as a "good" performance?

Comment: right now it is taking around 25 seconds each write cycle, for me i prefer not to reduce the size of chunk, i have slow DB, so better for me to reduce the number of DB calls by increasing the chunk size, btw i am doing DB batch calls in writer listener.

Comment: In this case, it could be that your db calls in the writer listener that are slowing things down (since your db is slow). To answer your question, there is no buffer size you can set on the `FlatFileItemWriter`.

Comment: I am talking about write function only, the write to CSV part, i am running all batch SQL calls on before write and logging time, my only struggle here is with write to CSV, there are not DB calls included